# How can I debug the Modx "mxCalendar" extra?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I hope someone is here, who is familiar with the cms Modx.

I installed the extra "mxCalendar" and my button "Create New Calendar Item" is not working. I click on it and nothing happens.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mxCalendar is not actively maintained anymore. Which MODX version are you using? mxCalendar does not work in MODX 2.3 and up, according to [this list](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues/11630).

I suggest to use another calendar system like integrating Google Calendar or use regular resources and add some date/time tv's to work with dates. It really depends on how you want to use the calendar. Think about questions like:

- Do I need (auto) recurring events?
- Can an event occupy multiple days?

If both questions are anwsered with 'yes', than it could become technically very complex in my experience. The best way to go is embedding Google Calendar, or it's API.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is sad but helping me very much.

Comment: Definitely an area of the MODX ecosystem that's lacking. It would be good if one of the companies providing premium Extras could come up with something.

Comment: Yes, it's a pitty that mxCalendar seems to be abandoned. It was a potentially good add-on.